# Linux c++ code modification for windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, powershell

I mostly use Linux for development, but Windows is the standard OS at the office. So I wrote a simple file manipulation code for the Windows environment.

The following code (for printing out lines of file) works fine in Linux, but when compiled in Windows, there is no output obtained after I run the executable.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
int main()
{
   std::ifstream stream;
   stream.open("n.txt");

   if(!stream)
   {
       std::cerr << "Rrror opening file.\n";
       return 1;
   }
   std::string result;
   while(std::getline(stream, result))
   {
       std::cout << result << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Following is the compilation command I give in Powershell:

```
g++ manip.cpp
```

The text file n.txt is as follows:

```
*DLOAD
362521,P1,-0.000129208
362524,P2,-1.67058e-005
362525,P1,-0.000105441
362528,P2,-1.87842e-005
362529,P1,-0.000106145
362532,P2,-1.84522e-005
362533,P1,-0.000105311
```

What can I do torun my program with the existing compiler?

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work in Windows? What compiler are you using in Windows? Is the executable and the file you try to read in the same directory in Windows? How do you test your program in Windows?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried to list the compiler above. Kindly suggest any other way you know to get the compiler. I am new to compiling programs in windows. Yes the files are in the same directory. I use `.\a.exe` in powershell to test the executable.

Comment: Okay, so the program compiles and links fine then? And the file you want to read is in the same directory as the executable? Then it *should* work. Except there might be one problem (which I will add an answer for).

Comment: Why not use Powershell's `get-content` aka `cat` cmdlet?

Comment: In future questions, please describe ***how*** something doesn't work. Does it give compiler or linker errors? Then add the *complete* and *unedited* error log to the question. Does the program crash when you run it? Then say so, and if possible add a debugger back-trace as well. Is the output not what you expect? Then add both the expected *and* the actual output to the question. This will make your problem much easier to diagnose, and will make it much easier for us to help you instead of us just guessing (which is what I have done with my answer).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have highlighted the problem and tried to be more descriptive about what's required.

Comment: Check the state of the stream after the `stream.open("n.txt")`. Try using `stream.good()` or `stream.bad()` or `stream.fail()`.

Comment: @ap-osd That `if(!stream)` check already does that.

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing that differs between Windows and Linux text files: Their line endings. Linux has plain newline (`"\n"`) while Windows have carriage-return *and* newline (`"\r\n"`).

If you try to read a file with Linux (or UNIX rather, as that's where it comes from) line endings on a Windows system, the line endings will not be recognized and it will be read as a single long line.

There are utilities on Linux side to convert line-endings (search for e.g. `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`), and most modern text-editors today (on both systems) can convert line endings as well.

It's easy to verify this problem by making a hex-dump of the text file, and see if the line ends with `0x0c 0x0a` or just `0x0a`.

Comment: I have created the program as well as the text files in windows.